# Backup operation fails for DB2

Tags: db2, backup, db2-luw, ibm-data-studio

I'm using Data Studio to connect to a DB2 database server (db2 server is running on a Linux box). The server disabled SSH password login and I can only SSH using a private key and a keyphrase.

I have configured SSH connection in Data Studio to use the private key and I'm able to establish a remote SSH connection from the Data Studio. But when I try to Back Up the database, it fails due to the following authorization error.

> com.ibm.datatools.cmdexec.RemoteExecutorAuthenticationException: com.ibm.tivoli.remoteaccess.RemoteAccessAuthException: CTGRI0000E Could not establish a connection to the target machine with the authorization credentials that were provided.CTGRI0000E Could not establish a connection to the target machine with the authorization credentials that were provided.CTGRI0000E Could not establish a connection to the target machine with the authorization credentials that were provided.

Any knows what's causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me... DataStudio 4.1.3 on Winx64, remote Db2-v11 on Linux x6, and I'm using the private-key of the Db2-instance owner account inside DataStudio.  However, my Linux allows *both* password-authentication and public-key authentication which may be significant.

In DataStudio, which Run Method have you chosen for the-backup?  The default is jdbc. Did you click "*Preview command*" to see what DataStudio will submit? For jdbc, it just runs SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD to perform the backup.

Does it make a difference if you chose a *run method* of 'Db2 server CLP' in the DataStudio tool?

There is also a technote advising of a [limitation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21665957), which may be relevant.